# my callback struct won't work

Tags: c, struct, callback

I have this code:

```
/* ... headers ... */

struct my_callback_struct {

    int data;
    int (*callback_func)(struct my_callback_struct *p, int data);
};

int reg(struct my_callback_struct *p, int data)
{
    return 1;
}

void init(struct my_callback_struct *p)
{
    p->callback_func = &reg;
}

int main ()
{

    struct my_callback_struct *p;
    init(p);

    printf("%d", p->callback_func(p,12));

    return 0;
}
```

so, basically I try to map p->callback_func with the function "reg". But when i compile it it says no errors but a segmention fault or something. I put a return of 1 just to check if it works...

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: But, this is not really a callback, isnt? Callback ist just when the function pointer is passed as an parameter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You simply haven't allocated memory for your `struct` instance. Try something like

```
 struct my_callback_struct s;
 init(&s);

 printf("%d", s.callback_func(p,12));
```

Or call `malloc` for your `p` before calling `init`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to allocate your callback struct.  The code as written is only a pointer to it.  Two opens are:

```
struct my_callback_struct p;  // Just "p", not "*p" which is a pointer
```

This allocates the struct on the stack.  Its memory will no longer be allocated when the enclosing function returns.  If you want it to have a longer lifetime you would most commonly use malloc() to dynamically allocate it:

```
struct my_callback_struct *p = (my_callback_struct*)malloc( sizeof( my_callback_struct ) );
if ( p == NULL ){
    return -1;     // Indicate failure to allocate
}
```